# GetWeekOfYear returns 2 while it should return 1 for date 02.01.2012

Tags: c#, datetime, week-number

Why does pseudocode below return 2 as Week number? Shouldn't it be 1?

```
string x = cal.GetWeekOfYear(02.01.2012 as datetime, cultureInfo.currentculture.DateTimeFormat.CalendarWeekRule, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek).toString();
```

Comment: Depends. What is `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` on your machine, under your user account?

Comment: Right, depending on the calendar settings, Jan 1st (a Sunday) may be the end (and start!) of week 1.

Comment: You can check this by examining the value of `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.FirstDayOfWeek`

Comment: It returns 1 if FirstDayOfWeek = Monday and CalendarWeekRule = FirstFourDayWeek.

Comment: @all, first day of week is "monday", current culture is TR-tr, CalendarWeekRule is FirstDay, but I am not able to figure it out by looking those values.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You say the [CalendarWeekRule](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.calendarweekrule.aspx) of your current culture is `FirstDay`, which is defined as (emphasis mine):

> Indicates that the first week of the year starts on the first day of
>   the year and *ends before the following designated first day of the
>   week*.

You also say the first day of your week is Monday.

January 1st, 2012 was a Sunday, and the first week starts with that day. Since the first day of your week is Monday, the first week ends before the following Monday, i.e. on Sunday itself.

Therefore, January 2nd, 2012 is indeed the first day of week 2 under your culture's settings.